# Why can't I use spaces around an f-string expression with a format specifier?

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

When I use f-strings with a format-specifier in a way like

```
>>> x = 1
>>> f'{ x:02 }'
```

It gives me `ValueError: Unknown format code '\x20' for object of type 'int'`. To fix this, I have to remove the surrounding whitespaces from the f-string expression, like `f'{x:02}'`.

Why is this so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given an f-string expression such as `f'{ x:02 }'`, the format specifier portion of the expression starts and includes all characters after the colon (`:`). This means that the space to the right of `02` is part of the format specifier. Despite what the error says, as said by [Chris Rands](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6260170/chris-rands), a space is a valid format code. What causes the error is that we used an invalid format specifier for an integer. Adding a space after `02` invalidates the specifier.

We can fix the problem with

```
>>> f'{ x:02}'
```

which successfully got me `01`. However, I *subjectively* do not recommend this style for f-string expressions since it looks imbalanced, i.e. the leftmost space has no pairing space at the other end of the expression. I would not use any surrounding spaces instead (e.g. `f'{x:02}'`).

---

**Recommended Reading**

- [PEP 498 - Literal String Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498)
- [PyFormat](https://pyformat.info/)

---

**EDIT:** I edited this answer to provide the correct explanation. In a previous edit, I incorrectly stated that a space is not a valid code in a format. Thanks, Chris, for the correction.